# Google apps script permissions issue

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been trying to set up Google apps script with a spreadsheet getting values from Tag Manager and I've used this before so I know it is working.

This is the tutorial Im using - https://measureschool.com/google-sheets-tracking-google-tag-manager/

However, when I try to set this up now I am getting an error and it has always worked before. I have clicked also the permission to "allow" the app.

The error I get is this:

{"result":"error","error":{"name":"Exception"}}

This error is given simply if I create a new apps script and deploy it. When I click on the link to test it, it shows me this error and the sheet remains disfunctional.

I also tried just creating the most simplest app with just "myFunction" function inside as the default and that doesnt work either and gives this error:

Script function not found: doGet

This is so confusing. Such a simple problem. Always worked before. Never had problems like this before. It's bizarre. Would be grateful for any helps.

This is the code that gives me the "name: error" message if I put this in a app script it.

```js
// Usage
// 1. Enter sheet name where data is to be written below
// 1. Enter sheet name and key where data is to be written below
var SHEET_NAME = "Sheet1";
var SHEET_KEY = "1jO5LaaIOfnAwkCCRpNPq0nee97ZjYh9D2YeJD_5OVys";

// 2. Run &gt; setup
//
// 3. Publish &gt; Deploy as web app
// - enter Project Version name and click 'Save New Version'
// - set security level and enable service (most likely execute as 'me' and access 'anyone, even anonymously)
//
// 4. Copy the 'Current web app URL' and post this in your form/script action
//
// 5. Insert column names on your destination sheet matching the parameter names of the data you are passing in (exactly matching case)

var SCRIPT_PROP = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties(); // new property service

// If you don't want to expose either GET or POST methods you can comment out the appropriate function
function doGet(e){
return handleResponse(e);
}

function doPost(e){
return handleResponse(e);
}

function handleResponse(e) {
var lock = LockService.getPublicLock();
lock.waitLock(30000); // wait 30 seconds before conceding defeat.

try {
// next set where we write the data - you could write to multiple/alternate destinations
var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SHEET_KEY);
var sheet = doc.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

// we'll assume header is in row 1 but you can override with header_row in GET/POST data
var headRow = e.parameter.header_row || 1;
var headers = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
var nextRow = sheet.getLastRow()+1; // get next row
var row = [];
// loop through the header columns
for (i in headers){
if (headers[i] == "Timestamp"){ // special case if you include a 'Timestamp' column
row.push(new Date());
} else { // else use header name to get data
row.push(e.parameter[headers[i]]);
}
}
// more efficient to set values as [][] array than individually
sheet.getRange(nextRow, 1, 1, row.length).setValues([row]);
// return json success results
return ContentService
.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"success", "row": nextRow}))
.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
} catch(e){
// if error return this
return ContentService
.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"result":"error", "error": e}))
.setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
} finally { //release lock
lock.releaseLock();
}
}
```

Comment: Did you included the `doGet` function?, in which line of code you're getting if i can ask?

Comment: I do include the doGet function in the script that Im using provided in the URL and in the code section. When I try to use the script given and then try to execute it using the test URL it is then that I get the error {"result":"error","error":{"name":"Exception"}}

My guess is that the doGet part of it is a bit of a misnomer because I think I resolved that by adding a doGet function and it seems to work, so perhaps this is something to do with the script? I dont get any other error message than this, so not sure where to look for errors?

Comment: I  checked your code, it is working absolutely fine.  Try checking Execution Page of your script, if there is Exception error for sure there will be log entry of it. Maybe you're using `sheetID`  or `Name`

Comment: @vector sorry its not working for me. I simple add the script, put my sheet id in and then deploy - then go to the URL (after all permissions allowed) and then it just gives me the name error. I wonder where is the execution page?

Comment: If you're new editor, it's `Execution Log` and if you're using legacy editor it is `View --> Execution Log`,

Comment: @vector Yes it says the script is running and completed. The error im referring to is happening when I click the test URL for the deployment? The script itself is supposed to allow you to append parameters from the deployment URL into the spreadsheet, however, nothing is showing up, so I am guessing this error is telling me something?

Comment: @vector thanks! it helped knowing that the script actually ran fine.

Comment: Welcome. good to know that it's resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this because I made a silly mistake in that my spreadsheet didnt contain the values timestamp and any params in the 1st line.